# Jsf selectOneMenu with items including commandLink Item

Tags: jsf-2.2

I need to add a command link Item to jsf selectOneMenu component as below:

[image]

The "New Item"  should be commandLink and on clicking it should open the dialog to add new Item.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Why *should* it be a commandLink? Why not just the text  "+ New Item" and on the server side detect this selection and open the dialog?

Comment: I know I can do this on server side but actually need this on the client side.

Comment: Then use an ajax handler on the compnent and in the onstart detect the value client side and open a dialog there. Might even be that returning false in the onstart prevents the ajax call to finish. All much easier than to hack a component